# Using Underscore (or Lodash), how do you remove every member of an array from another array?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying to use Underscore ( or Lodash) to remove every member of one array from another. For example, if I have the array

```
[1, 5, 2]
```

how do you efficiently remove every instance of every member of that array from some other array, such as:

```
[1, 1, 7, 2, 3, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]
```

I'm expecting to get:

```
[7, 3, 6, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8]
```

as the result. All my attempts with _.without() have failed, but I have a sneaking suspicion I'm just not calling it correctly.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`_.difference()`](http://underscorejs.org/#difference)...

> Returns the values from array that are not present in the other arrays.

```
_.difference([1, 1, 7, 2, 3, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8], [1, 5, 2]);
```

[Demo - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6KFD/)

Comment: Thanks, Anthony. Never ran across .difference(). Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Look at [difference](http://lodash.com/docs#difference)

```
var a = [1, 1, 7, 2, 3, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8];
var b = [1, 5, 2];

console.log(_.difference(a,b));
```